# android ignore non existing keywords in search function

Tags: android, database, keyword

Hye..I managed to create search function to search using multiple keywords. The problem is the keywords must be exist inside my database column that i had set. If i search using 3 keywords which is 2 keywords match inside database but 1 more keyword is not exist. The result was displayed nothing.

How could I ignore the non existing keywords?? just take the keywords that exists inside my database only. Means, if the user enter many keywords, system will read only keywords that match inside my database only and it will ignore the keywords that doesn't match. Below is my code.

```
String s = txtLelaki.getText().toString();
                String s = txtLelaki.getText().toString();
                String[] words = s.split(" ");
                String sql = null;

                String where = helper.KEY_LELAKI + " = ?";
                String relation = " or ";
                String wildcard1 = "'%";
                String wildcard2 = "%'";

                StringBuilder build = null;
                for(int i=0;i<words.length; i++)
                {
                    words[i] = new StringBuilder(wildcard1).append(words[i]).append(wildcard2).toString();
                    if(i==0)
                        build = new StringBuilder(where);
                    else
                        build.append(relation).append(where);                       
                }

                Cursor c = database.query(helper.DB_TABLE_LELAKI, null, build.toString(), words, null, null, null);


                if(c!= null)
                {
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    int soalanColumn = c.getColumnIndex(helper.MASALAH_LELAKI);
                    int getId = c.getColumnIndex(helper.ID_LELAKI);
                    if(c.isFirst())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            idList.add(c.getLong(getId));
                            results.add(c.getString(soalanColumn));


                        }while(c.moveToNext());
                    }

                }

                adapter.updateList(results);
                listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            }//end try

                catch(SQLException e)
                {
                    Log.v("caer", e.toString());    
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite**
I still don't understand exactly what you want to do, but looking at your previous question: [android searching with multiple keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15141681/1267661), I assume that you want a query like this: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE foo like ? OR foo like ? ...` for each of your possible keywords.  You need to build this `WHERE` clause yourself:

```
String where = helper.KEY_LELAKI + " = ?";
String relation = " OR ";
String wildcard = "%";

StringBuilder builder;
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    // Surround the keyword with "%", i.e. "%cat%"
    words[i] = new StringBuilder(wildcard).append(words[i]).append(wildcard).toString();

    // Build the WHERE clause
    if(i == 0)
        builder = new StringBuilder(where);
    else
        builder.append(relation).append(where);
}

Cursor c = myDataBase.query(helper.DB_TABLE_LELAKI, null, 
        builder.toString(), words, null, null, null);
```

If `s` in your example is `"cat mustache pull"` your query will have every row that contains the keyword phrases "cat", "mustache", or "pull".

Comment: Sorry if my post was no complete..here i edit my question adding some codes.

Comment: i had tried your code..it shows no error...but when i tried to enter keyword, it display nothing inside my listview..i also try to debug, when entering 3 keywords, it looks like no problem because it looping 3 times inside for loop...I'll update my code above for you to check..~~