# using append and wildcard for search multiple keywords in database android

Tags: android, database, search, wildcard, keyword

im trying to develope an application that can search multiple value in the existing database, but i still have no idea how to generate the codes. i've read this before [android ignore non existing keywords in search function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162564/android-ignore-non-existing-keywords-in-search-function) but still dot get the idea.. anyone can help??
this what i've done, i just search by string added in editText

public ArrayList search() {

```
    db = getReadableDatabase();
    qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = {KEY_ROWID, KEY_SURA, KEY_INDO}; 

    qb.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "indo like "  + "'%b%'",null,
            null, null, null, " 25");
    String result = "";
    ArrayList<String> string = new ArrayList<String>();
    int index = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_INDO);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result =c.getString(index);
        string.add(result);
    }
    return string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
db.rawQuery("select KEY_ROWID, KEY_SURA, KEY_INDO from DATABASE_TABLE where indo like "%b%",null);
```

Comment: it's just looks like hava the same function but it use rawquery.. and it say "near "'%b%'": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, suraID, indo FROM QuranDB WHERE (indoLIKE '%b%')"